# How to compute the time complexity of a triple nested loop represented by $\sum_{i=1}^{2n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=j}^{n} i-j$

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, closed-form, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

```
var r = 0;
for(var i=1; i<=2*n; i++) {
  for(var j=1; j<=n; j++) {
    for(var k=j; k<=n; k++) {
      r = r + (i - j);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use summation to solve for it, but I'm having a bit of trouble.

I got this summation:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{2n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=j}^{n} i-j
$$

But after trying to get a closed form for this, I got $-n^4 + n^2$, which is surely not the answer.

Could you guys help me?

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=j}^{n} i-j$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}  (i-j)\cdot(n-j+1)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}  (ni-ij+i-nj+j^2-j)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n}   (ni\cdot n-i\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+in-n\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{n(n+1)}{2})$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n}   \left(i( n^2-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n)-\frac{n(n^2+3n+2)}{6}\right)$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n}   \left(i\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{n(n^2+3n+2)}{6}\right)$$
$$  \frac{2n(2n+1)}{2}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-2n\frac{n(n^2+3n+2)}{6}=\frac23 n^4 + \frac12 n^3 - \frac16 n^2.$$

But this isn't the time complexity of the loop. It is the value of the triple summation in closed form.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20i%3D1%20to%202n%20sum%20j%3D1%20to%20n%20sum%20k%3Dj%20to%20n%20(i-j)),
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{2n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=j}^{n} i-j
= \frac23 n^4 + \frac12 n^3 - \frac16 n^2.
$$

But that is not the *time complexity* of the loop.
Instead, it is the *value of the variable $r$* at the end of the loop.

To get the time complexity, ignore the values that are getting added or subtracted to $r$ inside the loop. You just want the big-O class of the total number of operations performed.

A simple trick to count the operations is to replace $i - j$ with $1.$ This will undercount the operations, but not by more than some constant factor, and big-O means you don't have to worry about the constant factor.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=j}^{n} i-j = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n} \sum\limits_{j=1}^n (i-j) \cdot (n-j+1) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n} in^2 -\frac{in(n+1)}{2} + in - \frac{n^2(n+1)}{2} + \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{2n^3(2n+1)}{2} - \frac{2n^2(n+1)(2n+1)}{4} + \frac{2n^2(2n+1)}{2} - \frac{2n^3(n+1)}{2} + \frac{2n^2(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - \frac{2n^2(n+1)}{2} = \frac{2}{3}n^4 + \frac{n^3}{2} - \frac{n^2}{6} $$